# HTML server sent events

Tags: html

I have a little understanding on how server sent events work. Say I have a Linux server(remote server) and I need to monitor it's CPU usage from local machine continuously (via a HTML page which will be in my local machine). Will I be able to get the CPU usage continuously from the server to local machine using SSE? If so, I need some clarifications on how to do so. Or is there any other alternatives that I can go with without involving any softwares or so?

Comment: Use any server side language ,to send data to your html page

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [write some code to run on the server](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/tree/master/server-sent-events), which will gather whatever data you need.  (Common choices include Node.js, PHP, etc.)

That code will need to either directly serve HTTP requests, or connect to a web server.

Your code will send data in this format:

```
event: someevent
data: {"key": "value"}
```

Then, your client-side will use EventSource:

```
const eventSource = new EventSource('https://example.com/your-sse-path');
eventSource.addEventListener('someevent', (e) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(e.data));
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! So this php will be running on my server and this event source part should be included in my html right? So once executed this php will be continuously running on my server right? And one more thing shd I include port number anywhere on the script?

Comment: With PHP, that script should only be running while there is an active connection.  (At least, if your PHP configuration is set up correctly with your web server.)  The web server will execute PHP (or instruct PHP-FPM or whatever to do it) on-demand.  Obviously, you'll need to replace `https://example.com/your-sse-path` with the URL your script is at, including the port number if required.